# Finding differential surface element dS for a given shape

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

I need to find the differential element `dS` in terms of `dx` and `dy` for a shape drawn in the `x-y` plane. The shape consists of a triangle with one of its edges rounded. This arc at the edge is a part of a circle whose center is at the origin. The triangle also has one of the vertices at the origin (shown in the diagram).
[image]

The figure is symmetric about the x-axis. I have the equations that define the boundaries of the figure, but I need to find the differential surface element of this shape. I am trying to use this in an electromagnetics problem for finding the vector potential along this surface. The equation has one of the parts as a surface integral - $\iint\limits_S{J*G.dS}$ along the surface `S` given by the boundaries in the diagram (J and G may or may not be constants).

If I use the property $\iint\limits_S{F.dS} = \iint\limits_S{(F.\hat{n})dS}$ where $\hat{n}$ is the unit vector along the normal of the plane, I encounter a problem:

$dS = \frac{dxdy}{|\hat{n}.\hat{k}|}$ and $\hat{n} = \frac{\nabla{f}}{|\nabla{f}|}$ where f defines the boundary of the surface. However, since $\nabla{f}$ does not contain a `z` component, there isn't any $\hat{k}$ component in $\hat{n}$. This means the denominator in the RHS of `dS` is 0.

How do I find `dS`?

Comment: It would probably be better to use polar coordinates rather than dx, and dy. The geometry of your surface is much easier in that case. The surface element is just $rdrd\theta$ and and you simply let the limits of integration range in $ r\in [ 0, R ] $ and $ \theta [ \theta_0, \theta_1 ] $ where $R$ is the radius of the circle and $\theta_0, \theta_1$ are the angles of the two line segments. You can always convert the potential into Cartesian coordinates after you're done with polar coordinates.

Comment: As far as the z component is concerned, it's perpendicular to the page. The electric field functions in 3 dimensions.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the formula. If $dS$ is a small piece of area on your surface then we can represent it with a vector whose magnitude represents the  area and whose direction represents its orientation. Then $\lvert dS\rvert\cos{\theta}=dA$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the vector form of $dS$ and $\hat k$. That's the point of the transformation. You convert an integral over a surface into an integral in the plane.

Comment: If your figure is symmetric about the x axis then you can replace $\hat k$ with $\hat i$. In this case you are projecting $dS$ onto the yz plane instead of the xy plane. Your integral will then be over $dydz$. The same trick can be used if you want to project onto the xz plane.